# Remove specific param from url in javascript

Tags: javascript, search, location, document

Is there some way I can remove one specific parameter from url in javascript without reloading the page with document.location.search = newParams; ?

Comment: Why would you want to "remove" it? There's no way you can change the URL without refreshing.

Comment: it's complicated :) if there is no way to remove it than I will search  solution where the refreshing is not a problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with [HTML5 pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), which only works in modern browsers. An alternative is to change location.hash, which does not reload the page.

Comment: An alternative is to change location.hash, which does not reload the page. Thought about that but it's already in use by other value.

Comment: you could make hash encode multiple parameters. i.e. blah.com/#name=bob&age=8

Comment: At some point you may want to look into a library such as http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history-js

Comment: Thanks. multiple parameters in hash is tne best solution in my case. Why did I not think of this....